# Redirect a domain alias a primary domain page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a domain alias which we would like to redirect to the main primary domain which is working all good and well, but how do we redirect the domain alias to a page on the main website.

I have the following code in the .htaccess added (as below) but it is redirecting to the homepage which also breaks the actual page we want to redirect too.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainalias\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pirate-golf [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pirate-golf [L,R=301,NE]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pirate-golf$ https://www.domainalias.co.uk [L,R=301,NE]
```

We want the domain alias to redirect to the main domain page like the following example: [www.domainalias.co.uk](http://www.domainalias.co.uk) to redirect to [www.maindomain.co.uk/pirate-golf](http://www.maindomain.co.uk/pirate-golf).

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Could you please post samples of urls which will help us to understand your question in better manner, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated the question with the actual domain URL's

Comment: Thanks for editing, actually I didn't mean to post actual urls(samples will always work). My request is to mention url like: `http://www.subdomain.exmaple.com/blabla` to `http://mainone.example.com/something` you want to redirect?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I mis-understood. We would like to redirect the following domain alias www.domainalias.co.uk to https://www.maindomain.co.uk/pirate-golf

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainalias\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://maindomain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Make sure these rules are at the top of your htaccess rules file.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. I have just tried this but it redirects to the homepage every time.

Comment: @Craig, ok I have edited my answer now, could you please do check them(edited ones) and let me know then?

Comment: ok thanks. I have updated the redirects and it goes to the homepage of the main website

Comment: @Craig, could you please confirm if we are Good here?

Comment: thanks but the redirect is working as we want it too, it still redirect to the homepage and not the actual page

Comment: @Craig, ok could you please confirm if you have sub-domain created?

Comment: we have set as a domain alias and there are no sub domains

Comment: @Craig, Ok, do you have any other rules apart from my suggested ones?

Comment: apologies for my late reply. No there are no other rules in the htaccess file apart from the ones you have suggested.